# Erro ao rodar migrate

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel, migrations

```
Schema::create('filiais', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('filial', 30);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('produto_filiais', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('filial_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('produto_id');
        $table->decimal('preco_venda', 8, 2);
        $table->integer('estoque_minimo', 8, 2);
        $table->integer('estoque_maximo', 8, 2);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('filial_id')->references('id')->on('filiais');
        $table->foreign('produto_id')->references('id')->on('produtos');
    });

    Schema::table('produtos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn(['preco_venda', 'estoque_minimo', 'estoque_maximo']);
    });
```

Após rodar o `php artisan migrate`, ele dá o seguinte erro:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect
> table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be
> defined as a key (SQL: create table `produto_filiais` (`id` bigint
> unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `filial_id` bigint
> unsigned not null, `produto_id` bigint unsigned not null,
> `preco_venda` decimal(8, 2) not null, `estoque_minimo` int unsigned
> not null auto_increment primary key, `estoque_maximo` int unsigned not
> null auto_increment primary key, `created_at` timestamp null,
> `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate
> 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Comment: a mensagem é bem clara *"there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"*, em tradução livre *"pode haver apenas uma coluna automática e deve ser definida como uma chave"*

Comment: Se desejar usar chave primária auto increment  veja https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-increments e https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-bigIncrements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bem vindo a comunidade.

Aparentemente o erro está ocorrendo pois a migração está tentando criar mais de um campo com o recurso `auto_increments` e isso não é possível no MySQL.

**Solução:**

Remover os parâmetros que estão sendo passados para os campos inteiros, eles estão sendo mal interpretados pelo framework.

Qualquer coisa deixa o pq você passou esses valores para a gente entender melhor a tua necessidade.

**Lendo o log para entender o erro:**
[image: Log de erro enviado pelo colaborador]
O Log de erro está dizendo que temos 3 colunas tentando ser a chave primária, o que acaba por ocasionar o erro.

Ou seja, o problema está nas colunas definidas como integer que você está passando uns parâmetros a mais... Observando o que se pode passar ao criar uma coluna Integer podemos ver que o framework espera receber:

[image: Campos esperados ao criar uma coluna integer]

**Onde está o erro**

1º parâmetro = nome da coluna (string)
2º parâmetro = autoIncrement (booleano)
3º parâmetro = unsigned(booleano)

Observe que ao passar

```
$table->integer('estoque_minimo', 8, 2);
$table->integer('estoque_maximo', 8, 2);
```

O framework está lendo os números "`8`" como uma instrução para tornar o campo `auto-increment` (Não sei nem como funciona, pois está esperando um boolean)

**Indo além**

É possível ir mais a fundo e entender como a estrutura do integer é lido e trabalhada pelo framework, se ficar curioso pode dar uma olhada no arquivo `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint.php`
[image: Imagem de como uma coluna integer é interpretada pelo construtor]